# OData v4 query with $apply aggregate in expand fails with "Property access can only be applied to a single value" error in .NET 7 API with EDMs

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, odata, .net-7.0, odata-v4

```
public class FinancialRecord : IAuditable
{
    .
    .
    .
    public double Amount { get; set; } // this is the larger amount that the sum of the installments amounts need to get to.

    public ICollection<Installment> Installments { get; set; }
    
    .
    .
    .
}
public class Installment : IAuditable
{
    
    public double Amount { get; set; }

    
    public Guid FinancialRecordId { get; set; }
    public FinancialRecord FinancialRecord { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

I'm working on a .NET 7 API that uses Entity Data Models (EDMs) to expose financial records with their associated installments using OData v4. I'm trying to apply the $apply aggregate transformation on the Installments entity set to compute the sum of the Installments Amount column for each financial record, and use this information to determine if the financial record is fully paid or not by comparing it with the Financial Records Amount.

Here's the query I'm using:

```
https://localhost:7046/odata/FinancialRecords/?$expand=Installments($apply=aggregate(Amount with sum as Total))&$count=true&$filter=Installments/Total eq Amount and IsDeleted eq false&$orderby=PaidOn desc&$skip=0&$top=12
```

However, this query fails with the following error:

```
The parent value for a property access of a property 'Total' is not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value.
```

It seems that this error is related to accessing the computed "Total" property from the Installments entity set. Is there a way to fix this error and retrieve the aggregate sum of the Amount column for each Installment to determine if the financial record is fully paid or not?

Comment: Probably better to show your Model.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I just updated it, hope its clearer now, do let me know if its not. thanks.

Comment: Bad [news](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/2090). I don't know what they do 2 years with this.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv why do I keep talking myself out of using node.js by saying that .NET is the way to go because its "Scalable" and "multi-threaded"? None of my clients need scalability that much anyways.
Anyways, thanks a lot for answering man!

Comment: Does Node.js. has even comparable OData support?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Apparently, there are npm packages for serving and requesting data using OData on a nodejs server. But even if it didn't, once you're in the js ecosystem you'll most likely be exposed to things like GraphQL which I would guess has better support in nodejs than OData has on .NET Core even though OData is created by Microsoft itself.